# Probability of happening

Tags: probability

I have a question regarding probability. Probability that something will happen is 49.6% in first shoot. If this will not happen then probability is that it will happen 38.8% for next 7 shoots. What is the probability that the case will happen for shoot no. 2 till 7? Thank you! Konas

Comment: "for next 7 shoots" do you mean each of them? are they indendent? Also, what about the last trial (number 8)?

Comment: yes probability of first is 49.6, for second try 38.8, third 38.8, fourth 38.8...etc last trial is 8. and they are indendent on each other

Comment: I mean if it happened on say, the fifth trial, will the experience continue until 8 anyway? Or if it happened at the first trial, will the second trial happen anyway?

Comment: I believe that this is irrelevant I needed to know what is the probability for every trial (first one is known) but if I have two trials what is then probability of happening (49.6%, 38.8%), if I have three (49.6%, 38.8%. 38.8%) four (49.6%, 38.8%, 38.8%, 38.8%) etc. till 8 trial. Thank you!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is how I understand your question: You are doing an experiment that has a success probability of $49.6\%$. If that experiment fails, you will repeat a different experiment that is independent of the first and independent on previous attempts until succeeding. The second experiment has a success probability of $38.8\%$.

What is then the probabilty that we need $1,2,\ldots, 7$ experiments to succeed?

---

Denote 
$$
X_n = 1_{\{\text{success at trial n}\}}
$$
and assume all trials are independent, conditioned on the past trials, that is
\begin{align}
P(X_1 = 1) &= 0.496\\
P(X_n = 1 \mid X_1 = 0, \ldots, X_{n-1} = 0) &= 0.388, \quad n \geq 2
\end{align}

Then by conditioning,
\begin{align}
P(\text{success at trial 1}) &= 0.496
\\\\
P(\text{success at trial 2}) &= P(X_2 = 1)\\
&=P(X_2=1\mid X_1 = 0) P(X_1 = 0) \\&= 0.388(1-0.496)
\\\\
P(\text{success at trial 3}) &= P(X_3 =1)\\
&= \ldots\\
&= P(X_3 = 1\mid X_1 = 0, X_2 = 0)P(X_1 = 0)P(X_2 = 0)\\
&= 0.388(1-0.496)(1-0.388)
\\
&\vdots\\
P(\text{success at trial 7}) &= 0.388\cdot (1-0.388)^{7-2}(1-0.496)
\end{align}